Comparing the results of different classifiers on data sets with different prevalence
I have results for my classifiers on dataset A in ranked binary vector form. I want to compare these with existing results from an existing classifier applied to a larger dataset which has different prevalence. These are also in a larger ranked binary vector. Part of the research involves the differing structure of the two datasets being used in the classifier so I cannot just reapply one classifier to the other dataset.  I feel it is comparing apples with oranges but is there any way of comparing these two vectors to see which predicts more true positives? Machine learning/stats is not my area.
